# Questions regarding programming language codes

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate to ask questions regarding programming language codes like Java codes over here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as it is related to Ubuntu, it is on-topic. Questions that ask about general programming things ( like how do I use ArrayList in Java ) belong on other sites, Code Review or Stackoverflow

Comment: I agree of course. In practice, there is quite a grey area however. Many cli questions (including the linux- specific script languages), in practice allowed on AU, have nothing to do with Ubuntu specifically, and can be perfectly answered without even running or knowing Ubuntu. I can imagine newbies are confused sometimes :).

Comment: If we only allowed questions that only applied to Ubuntu, we'd have no questions at all :)